# How do I throw multiple exceptions in one constructor?

Tags: java, exception, constructor

I was wondering how can I execute both of these exceptions in the same constructor.  My program compiles fine, but it won't throw the exception for the second if statement.

```
public Segment(Point firstPoint, Point secondPoint) {
    if(firstPoint == null || secondPoint == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot pass a null value");
    if(firstPoint == secondPoint)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Segment cannot be 0");

    this.endPoint1 =  new Point(firstPoint);
    this.endPoint2 =  new Point(secondPoint);
}
```

Comment: You can't. One exception max.

Comment: learn to put `{}` around ALL `if/elseif/else` statements! If either of the points is `null` it will never get to that line. There is nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: Also, `firstPoint == secondPoint` is a reference equality comparison, not a test of whether the two objects represent the same position.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by throwing two exceptions? If you make throw, than method stops. If you need to combine messages, so you can do something like this:

```
//Parameterized constructor
public Segment(Point firstPoint, Point secondPoint)
{
    String error = "";
    if(firstPoint == null || secondPoint == null) {
        error  = "Cannot pass a null value";
    }
    if(firstPoint == secondPoint) {
        error = error.equals("") ?
                "Segment cannot be 0" :
                error + ". Segment cannot be 0"
    }

    if (!error.equals("")){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Segment cannot be 0");
    }

    this.endPoint1 =  new Point(firstPoint);
    this.endPoint2 =  new Point(secondPoint);
}
```